# Emploi de ès (en+les)

Tags: usage, prépositions, contractions

Même si cette préposition contractée a quasiment disparu de nos jours (voir https://lemondedufrancais.com/2012/02/01/lexpression-du-jour-docteur-es-sciences/), on l’a préservée ès dans la dénomination des grades universitaires.

Docteur ès sciences.

1. S est-il muet ou non?

Considérons la phrase:

> Je souhaite devenir professeur ès sciences.

2. Lors d'un emploi hors du monde académique ès est connu ou faut-il le remplacer par en les ?

> Je souhaite devenir professeur en les sciences.

3. Y a-t-il d'autres cas dans lesquels ès s'emploie ?

Comment: "en les" n'existe pas en français, on dira "professeur en sciences" ou "professeur de sciences". Je n'ai malheureusement pas les réponse à vos autres questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Le *s* final de *ès* est prononcé, comme si l’on disait *esse*.
2. Dans les autres cas, on remplace plus simplement *ès* par *en*, qui a une valeur générale et rend superflu l’ajout de *les* :

   > Je souhaite devenir professeur en sciences.
3. D'après *Le Petit Robert*, il existe un emploi juridique dans l’expression « ès qualités », qui signifie « en tant que représentant de la fonction qu’on occupe » et non en tant que personne propre.
   Par exemple :

   > Me DURANT es qualités de liquidateur de la société XXX

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! Je crois que c'est Mme DURANT et non Me.

Comment: @dimitris Il s'agit ici de *[**Maître**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%C3%AEtre_(droit)) Durant*.

Comment: Oh ! Quelle bêtise de ma part. Merci encore !

Comment: [Concernant la prononciation](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A8s), un bon historique et quelques subtilités dans l'usage du mot dans les noms propres de lieux.